# Why the below program gives the output :A

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

Why the below program gives the output :A.

what is use of `\n` after the format specifier `%d`?
I have tried it on Linux, Windows and [ideone](http://ideone.com/2MKcy).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char p[]="%d\n";
    p[1]='c';
    printf(p,65);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could try it on a platform using EBCDIC.

Comment: @DanielFischer, *high fives for having the same thought*

Comment: Re edit: It's not required, but it's more readable if you have the output on its own line, and what has the new title to do with aour question?

Comment: @downvoter : can anyone give me the reason why it is downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your program modifies the format string: it becomes "%c\n". Then it prints 65, which is re-interpreted as an ASCII code, which is an upper-case `A`.

This is identical to

```
printf("%c\n", 65);
```

or even

```
printf("%c\n", 'A');
```

because `char` values are converted to `int` when passed to variadic functions such as `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

ASCII character encoding. A is 65. http://www.asciitable.com/

You are changing the output format specifier from %d - integer to %c - character

Answer (score 2):

`%c` means `char`.

65 is the ASCII code of 'A'.

Answer (score 2):

Let's follow the flow of execution and the state of the variables. Initially, you are setting the string p = "%d\n". The '%d' tells printf to print an integer in the place of '%d' and it would be passed after the string argument to printf. You then are setting p[1] = 'c'. Which changes p to "%c\n", because arrays are indexed starting at 0 so you change the second character when you reference the 1 position. They you call printf with p and 65, which makes the call look like this: 'printf("%c\n", 65)'. The %c tells the printf function to replace the %c with a character passed as the second argument. In C, characters are represented as integers in the ASCII table (can be found here: http://www.asciitable.com/). It just so happens that 65 is the code for 'A', so an 'A' followed by a newline is printed. I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

With the format string `"%c"` you specify that `printf` should print a character. *65* is the ASCII value of the character 'A'.

You'll find more about ASCII on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii), including a table of character values.